# Replace each host route with ipset+mark and one route

Tags: ip, router, iptables

I need to route large number of IP via specific connection. I want to use IPSET for this purpouse instead of adding one route per each IP.
I am trying to run following example on `machine1`:

```
ipset create TEST hash:net
ipset add TEST 8.8.8.8
ipset test TEST 8.8.8.8
#8.8.8.8 is in set TEST.
iptables -I OUTPUT -t mangle -m set --match-set TEST dst -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add prio 100 fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add table 100 default dev eth1
```

Note, `eth1` on `machine1` is a vpn connection. Now I am trying to run `ping 8.8.8.8` on `machine1` but it shows me `Destination Host Unreachable`. On vpn machine I can see incomming requests with tcpdump, but looks like that `machine1` ignores or does not retrieve traffic back. Can someone tell me what is missing, please?

upd: on remote machine I observing only arp requests, not sure if it is important information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that it is problem with `Reverse Path Filtering` functionality at linux kernel where default value on some systems is set to verify routes. It makes you network more secure, however... in case of marking packets and route them through abstract rules may require to switch `rp_filter` to `2`, which will allow to accept asymmetrically routed packets.

You need to set is only ti interface, through which is planned to send/receive traffic.

Additional help available at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031